# How to display Monday as first day CalendarView

Tags: java, android, calendar, calendarview

With:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
```

you just set Monday's integer value to 0, but I want to have Monday displayed as first day (at the left end, and Sunday at the right)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use xml parameter android:firstDayOfWeek with value from Calendar. 2 - is Monday.

```
    <CalendarView
    android:id="@+id/calendarView1"
    android:firstDayOfWeek="2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="157dp" />
```

Or you can specify it from code

```
    CalendarView calendarView = findViewById(R.id.calendarView1);
    calendarView.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
```

Answer (score -4):

```
String[] days = null;
DateFormatSymbols names = new DateFormatSymbols();
days = names.getWeekdays();

for (int i=1; i<8; ++i) {
    system.out.println(days[i]);
}
```

Comment: where do i have to implement this?